# JSON Dictionary object to string in Swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I am having a heck of a time trying to convert a dictionary object to a string I can export to a .json file.  I have tried :

```
let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(JSONDictionary, options: .PrettyPrinted)
```

This fails immediately :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write
>   (__NSDate)'

Here is my dictionary object :

```
["latitude": 33.97300288084333, "longitude": -118.4644781426698, "parseID": qJd7QRojdU, "waves": (
        {
        avgSpeed = 0;
        course = 0;
        distance = "43.9934345945615";
        favorite = 0;
        maxSpeed = "5.420000076293945";
        time = "7.99999898672104";
        timestamp = "2016-02-05 16:05:21 +0000";
        wavelocation =         (
                        {
                altitude = 0;
                course = "78.046875";
                latitude = "33.9730028808433";
                longitude = "-118.46447814267";
                speed = "0.8199999928474426";
                timestamp = "2016-02-05 16:05:21 +0000";
            },
                        {
                altitude = 0;
                course = "71.3671875";
                latitude = "33.9730207342971";
                longitude = "-118.464455930626";
                speed = "1.080000042915344";
                timestamp = "2016-02-05 16:05:22 +0000";
            },
                        {
                altitude = 0;
                course = "69.2578125";
                latitude = "33.9730514958817";
                longitude = "-118.464368926472";
                speed = "1.080000042915344";
                timestamp = "2016-02-05 16:05:23 +0000";
            }

        );
    },
        {
        avgSpeed = 0;
        course = 0;
        distance = "112.301783225658";
        favorite = 0;
        maxSpeed = "4.670000076293945";
        time = "34.5915005803108";
        timestamp = "2016-02-05 16:36:56 +0000";
        wavelocation =         (
                        {
                altitude = 0;
                course = "-1";
                latitude = "33.9713087717363";
                longitude = "-118.463766921188";
                speed = "-1";
                timestamp = "2016-02-05 16:36:56 +0000";
            },
                        {
                altitude = 0;
                course = "58.8995221253856";
                latitude = "33.9713248007833";
                longitude = "-118.463470063933";
                speed = "3.448220014572144";
                timestamp = "2016-02-05 16:37:09 +0000";
            },
                        {
                altitude = 0;
                course = "61.875";
                latitude = "33.9713574294317";
                longitude = "-118.463396206608";
                speed = "3.710000038146973";
                timestamp = "2016-02-05 16:37:10 +0000";
            }

        );
    }
), "favorite": 0, "idleTime": 0, "paddleDistance": 2392.602, "distance": 0, "locationName": Venice Pier, "duration": 3730, "paddleTime": 412]
```

I'm scratching my head on this.  I have dug around SO for a while (2 days) looking for the answer but nothing is popping up.  Any help is appreciated! - Rob

Comment: Values for `timeStamp` key  seem to be `NSDate` where they should be `NSString`. That could be the issue according to your error message. You need to convert them (using `NSDateFormatter`).

Comment: Can you provide your code for the object you are trying to serialise into JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, you may need to convert any `NSDate` objects to `String` objects in your dictionary.

Assuming that you need the specific timestamp format detailed in your question, you can use a NSDateFormatter with [Unicode Date Formatting](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Some *rough* sample code below gives a demo of how to achieve this:

```
// get the current time as an example NSDate
let now = NSDate()

// format the date into the timestamp string using NSDateFormatter
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss xxxx"
let dateAsString = formatter.stringFromDate(now)

let dictToConvert = ["name": "Igor", "gender": "male", "time":dateAsString]

let savePath = NSHomeDirectory() + "/file.json"

do {
    let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictToConvert, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    if data.writeToFile(savePath, atomically: true) {
        print("saved file in location: \(savePath))")
    } else {
        print("could not write file to location: \(savePath)")
    }
} catch {
    print("error: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method of dealing with dates that is easy to exchange with a web service is to use the Unix Time Stamp - which is a number rather than a string.

To get the Unix Time Stamp:

```
let timestamp = date.timeIntervalSince1970
```

And to convert this back into a date:

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
```